# Logging into Skype breaks wireless connection

Tags: 10.04, networking, skype

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and just installed skype. Whenever I try to sign into skype, my internet connection breaks. I remain connected to my wifi network but can't connect to the internet.

The login hangs a while, I can't go anywhere in a browser or even ping a known host. The only thing that helps is uninstalling and restarting the computer. I've uninstalled skype for now, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.